# Magento set invoice to capture shows login screen, backbutton generates email with invoice

Tags: php, email, magento, invoice

When I click on "capture" in an invoice, Magento 1.7.0.2 shows the login screen. Clicking on the backbutton generates and sends an email with invoice pdf to the customer.

What is causing this behavior?

---

From some other post, but not helping:

I have set  System > Configuration > SALES > Sales Emails > Invoice to YES because it has to send an Invoice to the customer once the order is completed.

The problem is, if I set System > Configuration > SALES > Sales Emails > Invoice to NO, the mail with pdf-invoice on completing the order in the frontend will not be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the behavior is caused by a module called vianetz